# Google Drive: 500 Internal Error

Tags: google-drive-api

I get this excepiton when requesting certain files. Any way to debug?

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 OK
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal Error",
    "reason" : "internalError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal Error"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:159)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.execute(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:203)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClient.executeUnparsed(GoogleClient.java:237)
    at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest.executeUnparsed(JsonHttpRequest.java:207)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.executeUnparsed(Drive.java:307)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.execute(Drive.java:331)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to pop up when I try to create a folder with an empty name.
A more meaningful error msg would be great.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to reproduce the issue and I reported it to the Drive engineers

Comment: That has been fixed. If you create a folder with an empty name, the default one (e.g. "New Folder") will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Using version `0.5.1-dev` of [`grive`](https://github.com/vitalif/grive2) on Ubuntu 16.04 I came across the error:

```
request failed due to temporary error: 500 (body: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}
). retrying in 5 seconds
```

It would retry and repeat the error.

The solution was to create a dummy file within the directory.

I have [opened an issue for this](https://github.com/vitalif/grive2/issues/129).